# Backbone get model not by ID

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, thorax.js

I have a backbone model of a patient, which I can use to pull patients from my Mongo database. But in addition to polling them by ID, I would like to be able to pull them by name. The only way I could think of doing this is to do something like:

```
class Thorax.Models.Patient extends Thorax.Model
  urlRoot: '/api/patients'
  idAttribute: '_id'
  fetch: (options = {}) ->
    if @get 'first' # has first name, lookup by that instead of id
      @urlRoot = '/api/patients/by_name/' + (@get 'first') + '/' + (@get 'last')
      @set '_id', ''
    super options
```

But overriding the urlRoot seems bad. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may just use [Backbone.Model#url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) as a method and apply all your logic there.
So if it is first name in the model use one url and else use default url root.

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/karefeqaje/edit?js) code for this (just convert to your `CoffeeScript`)
You may open network tab to see 2 XHR requests for 2 models I created they are different.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'your/url/root',

  url: function() {
    // If model has first name override url to lookup by first and last
    if (this.get("first")) {
      return '/api/patients/by_name/' + encodeURIComponent(this.get('first')) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(this.get('last'));
    }

    // Return default url root in other cases
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.url.apply(this, arguments);
   }
});

(new Model({ id: 1, first: 'Eugene', last: 'Glova'})).fetch();
(new Model({ id: "patient-id"})).fetch();
```

Also you may apply this logic to the `url` in `fetch` options. But I don't think it is good way.
Happy coding.